# Encode Imagefile to 64BaseBinary Format in android

Tags: java, android

My application requires image file to be selected from SD card and the selected image should be converted or encoded to base64 binary format string.I am able to fetch image file from SD card and fetch its path and name,  but unable to convert it to base64 binary format string.

Thanks,
Sumith.M.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert image into base64 string:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);   
byte[]  = baos.toByteArray(); 

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
In the above  line of code you have used Base64 class ,so which library should be imported in order to get access to Base64 class.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of Android earlier than 8 do not have [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) built in. You can use this class in that case.

```java
public class Base64 {
   private static final char[] S_BASE64CHAR = {
       'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
       'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
       'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
       'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
       'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
       'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
       '8', '9', '+', '/'
   };
   private static final char S_BASE64PAD = '=';
   private static final byte[] S_DECODETABLE = new byte[128];
   static {
       for (int i = 0;  i < S_DECODETABLE.length;  i ++)
           S_DECODETABLE[i] = Byte.MAX_VALUE;  // 127
       for (int i = 0;  i < S_BASE64CHAR.length;  i ++) // 0 to 63
           S_DECODETABLE[S_BASE64CHAR[i]] = (byte)i;
   }

   private static int decode0(char[] ibuf, byte[] obuf, int wp) throws Exception {
       int outlen = 3;
       if (ibuf[3] == S_BASE64PAD)  outlen = 2;
       if (ibuf[2] == S_BASE64PAD)  outlen = 1;
       int b0 = S_DECODETABLE[ibuf[0]];
       int b1 = S_DECODETABLE[ibuf[1]];
       int b2 = S_DECODETABLE[ibuf[2]];
       int b3 = S_DECODETABLE[ibuf[3]];
       switch (outlen) {
       case 1:
           obuf[wp] = (byte)(b0 << 2 & 0xfc | b1 >> 4 & 0x3);
           return 1;
       case 2:
           obuf[wp++] = (byte)(b0 << 2 & 0xfc | b1 >> 4 & 0x3);
           obuf[wp] = (byte)(b1 << 4 & 0xf0 | b2 >> 2 & 0xf);
           return 2;
       case 3:
           obuf[wp++] = (byte)(b0 << 2 & 0xfc | b1 >> 4 & 0x3);
           obuf[wp++] = (byte)(b1 << 4 & 0xf0 | b2 >> 2 & 0xf);
           obuf[wp] = (byte)(b2 << 6 & 0xc0 | b3 & 0x3f);
           return 3;
       default:
           throw new Exception("internalError00");
       }
   }

   /**
    *
    */
   public static byte[] decode(char[] data, int off, int len) throws Exception {
       char[] ibuf = new char[4];
       int ibufcount = 0;
       byte[] obuf = new byte[len/4*3+3];
       int obufcount = 0;
       for (int i = off;  i < off+len;  i ++) {
           char ch = data[i];
           if (ch == S_BASE64PAD
               || ch < S_DECODETABLE.length && S_DECODETABLE[ch] != Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
               ibuf[ibufcount++] = ch;
               if (ibufcount == ibuf.length) {
                   ibufcount = 0;
                   obufcount += decode0(ibuf, obuf, obufcount);
               }
           }
       }
       if (obufcount == obuf.length)
           return obuf;
       byte[] ret = new byte[obufcount];
       System.arraycopy(obuf, 0, ret, 0, obufcount);
       return ret;
   }

   /**
    *
    */
   public static byte[] decode(String data) throws Exception {
       char[] ibuf = new char[4];
       int ibufcount = 0;
       byte[] obuf = new byte[data.length()/4*3+3];
       int obufcount = 0;
       for (int i = 0;  i < data.length();  i ++) {
           char ch = data.charAt(i);
           if (ch == S_BASE64PAD
               || ch < S_DECODETABLE.length && S_DECODETABLE[ch] != Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
               ibuf[ibufcount++] = ch;
               if (ibufcount == ibuf.length) {
                   ibufcount = 0;
                   obufcount += decode0(ibuf, obuf, obufcount);
               }
           }
       }
       if (obufcount == obuf.length)
           return obuf;
       byte[] ret = new byte[obufcount];
       System.arraycopy(obuf, 0, ret, 0, obufcount);
       return ret;
   }


   /**
    * Returns base64 representation of specified byte array.
    */
   public static String encode(byte[] data) {
       return encode(data, 0, data.length);
   }

   /**
    * Returns base64 representation of specified byte array.
    */
   public static String encode(byte[] data, int off, int len) {
       if (len <= 0)  return "";
       char[] out = new char[len/3*4+4];
       int rindex = off;
       int windex = 0;
       int rest = len-off;
       while (rest >= 3) {
           int i = ((data[rindex]&0xff)<<16)
                   +((data[rindex+1]&0xff)<<8)
                   +(data[rindex+2]&0xff);
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[i>>18];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[(i>>12)&0x3f];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[(i>>6)&0x3f];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[i&0x3f];
           rindex += 3;
           rest -= 3;
       }
       if (rest == 1) {
           int i = data[rindex]&0xff;
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[i>>2];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[(i<<4)&0x3f];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64PAD;
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64PAD;
       } else if (rest == 2) {
           int i = ((data[rindex]&0xff)<<8)+(data[rindex+1]&0xff);
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[i>>10];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[(i>>4)&0x3f];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64CHAR[(i<<2)&0x3f];
           out[windex++] = S_BASE64PAD;
       }
       return new String(out, 0, windex);
   }

}
```